FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'
I'm trying to generate an .exe file with only a "main.py" and a "data.json". I've tried a few things found here but nothing works. Both files are in the same directory (so is the .ico file, btw).
I run this command in my terminal in PyCharm:
pyinstaller -F -w --icon=icon.ico --add-data "data.json;." main.py

And I get this kind of errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 321, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 135, in beginning
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'

Any help? Thank you.
